# Sharing a single file's change in hg (not the entire changeset)

Tags: mercurial, workflow

Scenario:

Setting up a corporate hg system. Devs are working on multiple branches, one per dev (more or less). We are loosely following this sort of model: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ControlledPractice.

Design/workflow constraints: repos are super long-term (10+ years); # of devs on repo is in the 10-30 range.

- DevA fixes a bug in 1 file.
- DevB needs the fixed file, but explicitly doesn't want the rest of DevA's work.

This is going to happen a *lot*, we anticipate.

There are several ways I can think of to handle this situation:

1. Bugfix is in a single changeset, which gets `hg transplant`'d from DevA's branch to DevB's branch (or a share-code branch).
2. Spawn off a named branch for the fix, spawning from DevB's start commit, so that it can be cleanly merged.

Problems:

1. Duplicate changesets might lead to confusion about where a given feature was implemented(but maybe not?).
2. Branch profusion after a few years of work on this codebase = not acceptable.

Are there other known ways to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to handle this is to have DevA be more careful about the parent changeset of his change.  Before devA commits the bugfix s/he should `hg update` to the earliest revision in which that bugfix could have been made (often that's the changeset in which the bug was introduced).  When Dev A commits s/he will see a message saying a new head was created.  That new head can then be pulled and merged into any branch or repo that has the bug without bringing anything else with it.

The key is that you when you pull a changeset you're required to have in your repo any changesets that are the ancestors of the changeet you're pulling, so if you want someone to be able to pull a fix you're doing without pulling all the other work you've done you just make sure the parent of the fix is a changeset they're sure to already have.

This does require slightly more forethought on the part of the developer, but is preferable to having the same change in the repo multiple times with different node ids, which as you note is problematic (and ugly).

These new heads are what some folks call "anonymous branches" and they don't proliferate in the same way named branches would.

Comment: Thanks Ry4an. I'm pretty sure that this (in some fashion) is about as clean as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

if you're moving changesets from one branch to another in the same repo, I would recommend the `transplant` command. In terms of knowing where the changeset came from, you can use the `--log` command to append some information to the commit message of the transplant. For example:

```
hg update default
hg transplant revX --log
```

would create a changeset on `default` with the following commit message:

```
<original commit message of revX>
(transplanted from fa10a36d94385723fc7ecfaacb189365509ee83e)
```

I don't know of a way to add the `--log` argument using the TortoiseHg v1.1.X, but you can certainly perform the transplant from the repo explorer GUI as well.

Comment: the bummer with transplant is you end up with the exact same change in your codebase with multiple node id's when when later Dev A and Dev B do merge their work it doesn't merge as cleanly as having the change in there only once.  Transplant is a great way to deal with "oops, I forgot someone might want this change w/o wanting its parent" but building a workflow that relies on it is suboptimal.

Comment: @Ry4an - yeah, I can see how this would be a bad practice for repetitive use... thanks for the insight.

Comment: Which isn't to say it doesn't happen all the time -- it does, but when possible doing a `hg update` to where you could earliest have fixed the bug is preferable.